# Azure iot hub & azure function: consumer group issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have iot hub in azure and azure function, which is triggered when a message from a device is sent. The function looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("Ingest")]
public async Task Run(
            [IoTHubTrigger("IoTHubName", Connection = "IoTHubConnectionString"

#if DEBUG
            , ConsumerGroup = "localdev"
#else
            , ConsumerGroup = "release"
#endif

            )] EventData[] messages)
{
   ...
}
```

`IoTHubName` and `IoTHubConnectionString` I'm getting from `local.settings.json` when developing locally and from env variables in azure (Configuration tab in the portal) in the release. Almost all the time it's working fine.

But sometimes function is not triggered. I eliminated, that it's somehow connected with the consumer group. Because when I change "release" to something new, the function starts to get triggered again. So, my main question: what can be an issue? How can I find if some other function listens to the same consumer group(which is likely not possible, but who knows...)? Or maybe how can I remove all consumers? In fact how to understand why my function sometimes is not triggered?

Comment: When an Azure function connects to an IoT hub it silently uses an epoch value. This essentially forces a consumer group to only have one listener. The one with the highest epoch value wins. is it possible that you have something else connecting to the release consumer group with a high epoch value that could be causing the function to fail to connect? You should always provide an Azure function with a dedicated consumer group.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

Provide Azure function with a dedicated consumer group. Refer architecture diagram below which is documented by Azure here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups

[image]

In the picture above, Azure function is one of the event listener and it has a dedicated consumer group. As per Azure `In a stream processing architecture, each downstream application equates to a consumer group.` In your case downstream application is Azure function. Also, if you have multiple consumers i.e. multiple Azure function listening to a consumer group then each consumer is listening to a particular partition i.e Azure funtion1 listens to partition 1 and Azure funtion2 listens to partition2. This will guarantee that the message is delivered to one of the consumer and not all of them.